# Paged list scrolls down to some page after multiple DB update operations

Tags: android, android-paging-library

I am using Paging with Room to display data from my DB in to the Recycler view.
Similar to this paging codelab https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-paging

I added a delete operation which deletes given item and some other item at a random position from DB and updates the list.
However if I scroll 2-3 pages down and then perform that operation then the paged list gets scrolled to some random page downwards.

Comment: Hey, I'm also facing the similar issue I'm also having a chat list performing the adding operations to the db multiple times it scrolls to some other page of list. I'm using the jetpack compose with pagination. Are you able to solve the issue?